# Subtracting values via MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, subtraction

quick question I just can't get my head around right now :

I have a table, called "liverace", which is as follows (excerpt):

```
racelap,pos,change,userid
1        1    0      21
1        2    0      12     
1        3    0      18
2        1    0      18
2        2    0      21
2        3    0      12
```

Basically, I have several laps listed as racelap where each user (with it's own unique "userid") gets a position assigned ("pos") depending on some calculus.
What I need to do here is to have the "change" column, be updated for each lap and each user to reflect the changes in position.
So I have to compare every position for each lap and each user i.e., it should show :

```
racelap,pos,change,userid
1        1    -      21
1        2    -      12
1        3    -      18
2        1    +2     18
2        2    -1     21
2        3    -1     12
```

First lap has no change since lap 0 does not exist. Lap 2 is where it should show the changes in position.

I've been trying some selects but nothing worked.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: this sort of thing is difficult/ugly to do in mysql. you'd be better off doing the calculations client-side.

Comment: @Farhang Amary it's an expression that means I don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  so1.`lap`,
  so1.`pos`,
  COALESCE(so2.pos - so1.pos, "-") as `change`,
  so1.user_id 
FROM
  so so1 
  LEFT JOIN so so2 
    ON so2.lap = (so1.`lap` - 1) 
    AND so2.`user_id` = so1.`user_id`
```

Works as intended .

```
   lap     pos  change  user_id  
------  ------  ------  ---------
     1       1  -              21
     1       2  -              12
     1       3  -              18
     2       1  2              18
     2       2  -1             21
     2       3  -1             12
```

Assuming the following

```
CREATE TABLE `so` (
  `lap` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```